# how to navigate with pinentry

Tags: command-line, gpg, gpg-agent, pinentry

I was was using `gpg --gen-key` till I got to enter the passphrase where I get:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Please enter Passphrase,                             │
│                                                      │
│ Passphrase: ________________________________________ │
│                                                      │
│       <OK>                            <Cancel>       │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

After some digging I found out this came from `gpg-agent` which in turn uses `pinentry`.

All I can do here is enter passphrase (which works fine) and press tab, which makes the blinking cursor disappear. But how to I select `<ok>` or `<cancel>` in `pinentry`?

`gpg` was installed on `osx` via `brew`

When I try `CTL+C` I get: `gpg: signal Interrupt caught ... exiting` but can still continue typing a passphrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the cursor in the PIN entry area, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will activate the “OK” button.

Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will highlight the “OK” button and then the “Cancel” button; pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> with a button hightlighted will activate that button.

Comment: `Esc` does nothing here.

Comment: Tested pressing `Tab` on ubuntu which worked fine highlighting `ok` and `cancel`. Doesn't show highlighting on osx, but works ! Thanks